# What is the max number which geth's targetgaslimit option can take?

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to put lots of data into one transaction in private geth network. What is the max number which geth's targetgaslimit option can take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at how the flag is set in [`flags.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/cmd/utils/flags.go#L184):

```
TargetGasLimitFlag = cli.StringFlag{
    Name:  "targetgaslimit",
    Usage: "Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine",
    Value: params.GenesisGasLimit.String(),
}
```

`GenesisGasLimit` itself is initialised to "million pi" as a big int:

```
params.GenesisGasLimit = big.NewInt(3141592)
```

[Elsewhere](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/290e851f57f5d27a1d5f0f7ad784c836e017c337/params/protocol_params.go#L45) in the code it continues to be handled as a big int. I can't immediately see anywhere in the code that imposes a limit on the value.